# How to reuse Generic from outer class in static inner class?

Tags: java

It is my understanding that the outer class' parameterized types are accessible to the inner class, possibly this isn't possible using a static inner class?

The below doesn't compile for me. I would like my static inner class to inherit its generic parameters from the wrapper class.

```
interface CarFactory<V, W> {
   W makeCar(V);
}

public abstract class Car<T, U> {

   ....

   public static class Factory implements CarFactory<T, U> {
    @Override
    public U makeCar(T model) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Any static member (including static class) cannot access the generic parameters...

Comment: There's no such thing as a static inner class; nested classes that are static by definition have no connection to the enclosing class and don't share per-instance information such as type parameters.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to solve? For example: What are the type parameters? If T/V is model, what is U/W? Why do you need a static factory in a generic class?

Comment: Change ```class Factory``` to ```class Factory<T, U>```.

Answer (score 1):

From [8.1.2. Generic Classes and Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2)

> It is a **compile-time error** to refer to a **type parameter of a generic class C** anywhere in:
>
> - the declaration of a static member of C (§8.3.1.1, §8.4.3.2, §8.5.1), or
> - t**he declaration of a static member of any type declaration nested within C**, or
> - a static initializer of C (§8.7), or
> - a static initializer of any class declaration nested within C.